# Possibilities to put together a value of $n$ euros from $1$ euro, $2$ euro coins, $5$ euro notes and $10$ euro notes

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $c_n$ be the number of possibilites to put together a value of $n$ euros from $1$ euro and $2$ euro coins as well as $5$ euro notes and $10$ euro notes.

How can one find out what the generating function of $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ is?

And how many possibilites are there to to put together a value of $10$ euros?

So for $10$ euros I thought of the following:

- $10$ times $1$€
- $8$ times $1$€ + $1$ time $2$€
- $6$ times $1$€ + $2$ times $2$€
- $4$ times $1$€ + $3$ times $2$€
- $2$ times $1$€ + $4$ times $2$€
- $5$ times $2$€
- $1$ time $10$€
- $2$ times $5$€
- $1$ time $5$€ + $5$ times $1$€
- $1$ time $5$€ + $3$ times $1$€ + $1$ time $2$€
- $1$ time $5$€ + $1$ time $1$€ + $2$ times $2$€

So a total of $11$ possibilites.

I kind of doubt that this is correct and I also don't know hot find out the generating function.

Comment: For a coin of value $d$ you get a factor of $\frac1{1-q^d}$ in the generating function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about the generating function...

Counting the number of ways to make change for $\$n$ is equivalent to counting the number of integer solutions to
$$
k_1+2k_2+5k_5+10k_{10}=n,\\\tag{*}
k_1,k_2,k_5,k_{10}\ge 0
$$
Here, $k_i$ represents the number of $\$i$ bills. I claim that this is the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$
(1+x+x^2+\dots)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+\dots)(1+x^{10}+x^{20}+\dots)\tag {**}
$$
This is because when expanding out the product of infinite sums in $(**)$, each term is a product of terms that look like $x^{k_1}(x^2)^{k_2}(x^5)^{k_5}(x^{10})^{k_{10}}$, so the number of summands equal to $x^n$ is the number of solutions to $(*)$.

Applying the geometric series formula to each factor in $(**)$, we get the generating function is
$$
\boxed{\frac1{1-x}\cdot \frac1{1-x^2}\cdot \frac1{1-x^5}\cdot \frac1{1-x^{10}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help with the generating function, but I can help you to count possibilities with a few lines of code:

Say that the initial amount is equal to $a$ and your coins have values $v_1<v_2<...<v_n$. Let us denote the number of possiblities with $c(a, v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$.

For your first coin you can pick the coin with the smallest value ($v_1$). In that case the remaining amount is $a-v_1$ and the number of ways to compose that value with the same coins is $c(a-v_1, v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$.

The other possibility is to stop using the coin with the smallest value and compose the amount $a$ with coins $v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n$. The number of possibilities would be $c(a, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n)$.

So we have the following recurrence formula:

$$c(a, v_1, v_2, v_3,\dots,v_n)=c(a-v_1, v_1, v_2, v_3,\dots,v_n)+c(a, v_2, v_3,\dots,v_n)$$

We need some exit conditions:

- If $a=0$, we are done. There is one way to produce zero amout (by not using any coins).
- If $a<0$, we are doomed. There is no way to produce negative amount with coins of positive value.
- If $a>0$ but we don't have any coins, it's not possible to produce the requested amount.

In Mathematica, we need only 4 lines of code:

```
c[amount_, coins_] := 1 /; amount == 0
c[amount_, coins_] := 0 /; amount < 0
c[amount_, coins_] := 0 /; amount > 0 && Length[coins] == 0
c[amount_, coins_] := c[amount, coins] = c[amount - coins[[1]], coins] + c[amount, Drop[coins, 1]];
```

In you example, you want to calculate:

```
c[10, {1, 2, 5, 10}]
```

...and it returns 11, so your calculation is correct.

But you can easily calculate the number of possibilities for much bigger values. For example, you can produce amount of 20 in 40 different ways, 50 in 341 different ways and 100 in 2156 ways. If you plot the number of possibilities for all total amounts, from 1 to 100, the graph looks like this:

[image]

The full list of {amount, combinations} pairs, from $a=1$ to 100 is here, just for reference:

```
 {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {6, 5}, {7, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 
      8}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 15}, {13, 16}, {14, 19}, {15, 22}, {16,
       25}, {17, 28}, {18, 31}, {19, 34}, {20, 40}, {21, 43}, {22, 
      49}, {23, 52}, {24, 58}, {25, 64}, {26, 70}, {27, 76}, {28, 
      82}, {29, 88}, {30, 98}, {31, 104}, {32, 114}, {33, 120}, {34, 
      130}, {35, 140}, {36, 150}, {37, 160}, {38, 170}, {39, 180}, {40, 
      195}, {41, 205}, {42, 220}, {43, 230}, {44, 245}, {45, 260}, {46, 
      275}, {47, 290}, {48, 305}, {49, 320}, {50, 341}, {51, 356}, {52, 
      377}, {53, 392}, {54, 413}, {55, 434}, {56, 455}, {57, 476}, {58, 
      497}, {59, 518}, {60, 546}, {61, 567}, {62, 595}, {63, 616}, {64, 
      644}, {65, 672}, {66, 700}, {67, 728}, {68, 756}, {69, 784}, {70, 
      820}, {71, 848}, {72, 884}, {73, 912}, {74, 948}, {75, 984}, {76, 
      1020}, {77, 1056}, {78, 1092}, {79, 1128}, {80, 1173}, {81, 
      1209}, {82, 1254}, {83, 1290}, {84, 1335}, {85, 1380}, {86, 
      1425}, {87, 1470}, {88, 1515}, {89, 1560}, {90, 1615}, {91, 
      1660}, {92, 1715}, {93, 1760}, {94, 1815}, {95, 1870}, {96, 
      1925}, {97, 1980}, {98, 2035}, {99, 2090}, {100, 2156}
```